# jQuery styled checkboxes won't stay inside asp panel with scroll bar

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

This issue ONLY happens in IE, everything works just fine with Firefox and Chrome.  I have a form that I wanted to use these sweet iPhone style jQuery switches with.  It's basically a styled checkbox.  The table that I have is inside a panel with a vertical scroll bar.  If I leave the checkboxes alone (no jQuery style), they stay inside the panel and scroll with all of the other elements.  As soon as the checkboxes are styled, they "break out" of the scroll panel and flow down the the page while all the other elements (labels and ddl's) stay inside the panel.  Here is the code for the jQuery styles that are applied:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.inOut:checkbox').iphoneStyle({
            checkedLabel: 'IN',
            uncheckedLabel: 'OUT'
        });
        $('.late:checkbox').iphoneStyle({
            checkedLabel: 'LATE',
            uncheckedLabel:'ON TIME'
        });
        $('.leaveEarly:checkbox').iphoneStyle({
            checkedLabel: 'YES',
            uncheckedLabel: 'NO'
        });
    });
</script>
```

The asp panel that the form elements go inside:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlDisplay" runat="server" ScrollBars="Vertical" Width="100%" Height="500px">
    <%-- Dynamically generated list goes inside this table from codebehind --%>
    <asp:Table ID="tblResults" runat="server" Width="98%" CellPadding="10">

    </asp:Table>
</asp:Panel>
```

Lastly, an example of one of the checkboxes that gets created in the codebehind:

```
CheckBox isIn = new CheckBox();
isIn.InputAttributes["class"] = "inOut";
```

Again, the issue is only in IE.  Any ideas?  (and scrap IE isn't an option as it is heavily used here in our office)

Comment: i think i know what you're talking about - we had a similar issue with checkboxes on IE as they appeared normal on load but as soon as they were clicked, they would change position and css rules would break. It turned out to be a border issue for us. I see that you are assigning your table results a width of 98%. What happens when you bump that up to 100%? or "inherit"?
I would also check your inOut class for any restrictions on height/width

Comment: I'll be more specific . . . the checkboxes are breaking out of the bottom of the panel.  So, the panel has a set height of 500px with a scroll bar.  There are roughly 130 rows to the table that the panel is holding.  Each row has these checkboxes, but instead of staying inside of the panel and scrolling with all the other content, they just keep going on their own and extend the scroll bar of the actual page, not the panel.  So in the panel you may only see 10 rows of the table, but you can see all 130 of the checkbox sliders on the page at once

Comment: is the content dynamically loaded? if it is, its possible your content which is being loaded may not be following your css rules. You may require a "refresh". not page refresh, just content refresh

does your css rule for pnlDisplay have an overflow rule for your y-axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, the resolution to this issue was to scrap the jQuery check boxes and go with something similar:  the ajaxControlToolKit toggle button extender.  This control gave me all of the same functionality that I wanted from the jQuery solution, but still stayed inside of the scrollable panel.  And since it is an asp control, I can create it dynamically in the code behind.

```
CheckBox isIn = new CheckBox();
     isIn.ID = "cbIn" + dtCoverage.Rows[i]["userId"].ToString();
     isIn.Attributes.Add("onClick", "OnClickInOut (this)");

AjaxControlToolkit.ToggleButtonExtender isInExtender = new AjaxControlToolkit.ToggleButtonExtender();
     isInExtender.ID = "tbeIsIn" + dtCoverage.Rows[i]["userId"].ToString();
     isInExtender.ImageHeight = 26;
     isInExtender.ImageWidth = 60;
     isInExtender.UncheckedImageUrl = "~/Images/noBtn.jpg";
     isInExtender.CheckedImageUrl = "~/Images/yesBtn.jpg";
     isInExtender.TargetControlID = "cbIn" + dtCoverage.Rows[i]["userId"].ToString();
```